# How do I get warning when a label is not defined but we are refering?

Tags: cross-referencing, warnings, examples

I am writing a lecture notes for M.Sc Students...

The first chapter was prepared some months ago and I forgot that the places that I have referred a particular example/exercise given in the first chapter.

Now, if I want to delete the example which is labeled, surely it will affect the reference.

How do I come to know that,

> What are the places I have given reference for  that  example/exercise automatically?

One crude way is to look into the output and search...

But I need the automatic solution, which much highlight the places where I have reference without a lable(since it has been assumed that the example got deleted).

Comment: TeXStudio is able to provide autocompletion of you labels. 
You could also you clear  label names with prefixes and chapters like `fig:chap1:example1` or `eq:chap4:schroedinger`

Comment: I don't understand the real questioni here. Do you want a mechanism that warns you if references are undefined?

Comment: Maybe describe the problem in your native language in more detail and add to the questin, what google translates for you.

Comment: @Johannes_B  exactly

Comment: So, to be sure: If `\label{david}` does not exist, you want a warning like `LaTeX Warning: Reference \`david' on page 1 undefined on input line 9.`

Comment: yes..@Johannes_B

Comment: David, check your log file. That mechanism is built in. That is the default. You don't need anything. It is standard. Just look at the log-file of your compile run.

Comment: And in document you see ?? for undefined reference. This means, that in your case "david" is not defined.

Comment: @Zarko I have quoted this solution already by "one way is crude search by looking this ?? symbol in the place referred". My question is different it should locate the undefined reference in the latex document itself.

Comment: If you're using Texstudio, simply doing the search ought to make you automatically jump to the correct line, or even word, in the .tex document.
In Texmaker, you can use Ctrl+Click on the PDF-viewer to jump to the corresponding line in the .tex document.

Comment: Aha, you have the problem: How to find something what not exist :-). Or you like to find, where in the code is your ref? This is editor/viewer issues and backward search capability of previewer. For example, Sumatra and WinEdit work quite well. The similar is at others editor. .